# Why does my awk command print an extra line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm finding it difficult to debug my shell scripts.  I have the following file test.csv

```
The Gardens,Gard (AUS),AEST,NSW,,Sandown Park,SPrk (AUS),AEST,VIC,,Grade 5,GR5,
Wentworth Park,WPrk (AUS) ,AEST,NSW,,The Meadows,Mead (AUS),AEST,VIC,,Juvenille,JUV,
Angle Park,AnPk (AUS),ACST,SA,,Warragul,Wgul (AUS),AEST,VIC,,,,
```

WPrk (AUS) has an extra trailing white space which I wish to trim and then print.  Running

```
awk -F\, 'gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2); {print $2 ":"}' test.csv
```

Produces

```
Gard (AUS):
Wentworth Park WPrk (AUS) AEST NSW  The Meadows Mead (AUS) AEST VIC  Juvenille JUV
WPrk (AUS):
AnPk (AUS):
```

Which is what I want except for the second line I can't figure out why that appears

Comment: try `printf(fmt, a1, a2, ...)`

Comment: try without printing `$2` maybe ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F\, 'gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2); {print $2 ":"}' test.csv
```

Since you have `gsub` outside any action block (`{...}`), it is evaluated every line *as a condition*.  It returns the number of substitutions it made, so it will return 0 on most of the inputs, but 1 on the lines you want to change. Since there is no action accompanying it, the default action is executed, printing the line; that is why you are getting the full line printed.

The fix, as others have said, is putting the `gsub` call inside the action block.

(Also, why `\,`? Comma is not a special character in the shell.)

Answer (score 2):

How about changing the command to be:

```
    awk -F, '{gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2); print $2 ":"}' test.csv
```

That's moving '{' to the front.

**Edited**
As others said, you don't need to escape comma, `-F,` is enough. Thanks to other answerers :).

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
awk -F\, 'gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2); {print $2 ":"}' test.csv
```

This is broken.

The format for an awk script is a bunch of constructs that look like:

```
   condition {
     command; 
     ... 
    }
```

The idea here is that each line in the input data is evaluated against *condition*.  If it matches, then the commands in the corresponding curly brackets are executed.  So what you probably want is more along the lines of this:

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $2); print $2 ":";}' test.csv
```

Note that you don't need to escape the field separator unless your shell will treat it badly (i.e. if it was a vertical bar, `|`, instead of a comma).  By excluding the condition inside the script, you execute the curly-braced commands on EVERY line.  So this will trim $2 whether it needs to be trimmed or not, then print the result per your example in your question.

Comment: It's not broken in the sense of syntax, just logically. As it is, it's evaluated as a condition.